# "cordova platform add android" shasum error

Tags: cordova

I'm working through the setup and HelloWorld example at
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0//guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface
on Debian Stable and running into a problem at the command

```
cordova platform add android
```

Output error message is:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/-/cordova-android-3.6.1.tgz
Unable to fetch platform android: Error: shasum check failed for .../tmp/npm-29259-W2mnHZlo/1410473956287-0.27467933809384704/tmp.tgz
Expected: b9138a0743c4f424ee62721c22dac84e8d1ca087
Actual:   a5c74dea5a0225566e4a54185d8639a7f7f6ac3e
```

I tried using wget to fetch
    cordova-android-3.6.1.tgz
, but

```
shasum cordova-android-3.6.1.tgz
```

returns the same a5c... checksum as above. I looked at
    registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android
in a browser, and it does specify the b91... checksum.

So, is this a bug, or is there a setting that changes how the shasum is computed? (the -a option of shasum changes the output, but none of the values produce a match).

12sep2014: Thanks. Both answers worked, but I don't have enough reputation to upvote them. I somewhat arbitrarily selected the longer answer as the "official" correct one.

Another workaround I found is the usegit option:

```
cordova platform --usegit add android
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was an error in packaging the NPM distribution of the latest cordova packages -- apparently related to https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5414

As a workaround, you can untar the cordova-android package that you downloaded, and run the command

```
cordova platform add <path_to_cordova_android>
```

The SHA-1 checksum of the official package at apache.org (https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/release/cordova/platforms/cordova-android-3.6.1.tgz) *does* match what you've found, so it's not an issue of file corruption at npm, just a error in the publishing process.

Answer (score 5):

this is an open bug
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7526

reinstall cordova

`sudo npm install -g cordova`