# Unable to fetch platform android: Error: Failed to parse json

Tags: android, cordova

Im running cordova version 4.3.0.

Suddenly, cordova commands have stopped working. I can create a new project. But when I go run:

```
cordova platform add android
```

I get:

```
Unable to fetch platform android: Error: Failed to parse json
Unexpected end of input
```

When I run the command "android" in Git Bash, I get the error:

```
 sh.exe": android: command not found
```

The "android" command works in Command Line. I get the same error on Command Line when trying to add the android platform.

In my Environmental Variables, PATH includes the paths:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools
```

Which are the correct paths to Android.

What could possibly be going on? Cordova has been working fine for months and then suddenly this..

Comment: Look at this, i think it will fix your Problem :-)

http://stackoverflow.com/a/25807768/3671726

Comment: Did you find a solution?

I have same issue. I tried to reinstall everything but still same error occurs.

Comment: yes, i will put up the answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to have been a problem with the npm cache getting corrupted. I deleted the folder `cordova-android` at `C:\Users\Mark\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\` then ran `cordova platform add android` again. Instead of using the cache, a new cordova-android is downloaded. Haven't had any problems since.